# create a cmd file with a loop (wget recursive download)

Tags: windows, cmd, wget

What i have done :

```
wget -e robots=off --mirror -np --no-check-certificate https://awebsite.com/.../page1.html
```

my cmd code :

```
for i in {1..400}
do 
    wget -e robots=off --mirror -np --no-check-certificate "http://website.com/.../page$i.html"
pause
```

Edit: I use windows. I mixed up
Thank you in advance

Edit 2 :

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,3) DO (
    set num=%%G 
    wget -e robots=off --mirror -np --no-check-certificate "https://website.com/.../page!num!.html"
)
ENDLOCAL 
pause
```

But it download `page1 .html` and `page2 .html` and `page3 .html` (always a space... :/)

Comment: Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Ok, but my cmd closes itself and i can't find the downloaded files

Comment: `@echo off` is not a valid Bash command, nor is `pause` a standard Unix command. You seem to be mixing Bash and Windows CMD syntax.

Comment: Is the goal to produce a  cmd.exe .bat file script or a bash script? Are you asking that someone convert the bash command into a cmd command?

Comment: Is it possible to make a loop in cmd ? I want to create a .cmd But I don't know much about it (just few python tips or how to use visualWget)

Comment: Of course, loops are possible in `cmd`. The syntax is different though. Read the output of `for /?` and/or visit [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/)

Comment: Thanks. Please look at edit n°2

Comment: Well, you explicitly tell it to add a space: `set num=%%G<SPACE>`. Better use the preferred syntax `set "num=%%G"` to avoid unwanted (and invisible and therefore hard to spot) trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It works !!!

`SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,3) DO (
    set "num=%%G" 
    wget -e robots=off --mirror -np --no-check-certificate "https://website.com/.../page!num!.html"
)
ENDLOCAL 
pause`

Comment: btw: if that's all you want to do, you don't need the `num` variable and so also no delayed expansion. Inside the loop, you can use `%%G` directly: `wget -e robots=off --mirror -np --no-check-certificate https://website.com/.../page%%G.html"